# CMS with rich text and embedded audio, video, interactive graphics hosted on Azure

Tags: web-development, cms

We have a website powered by the DotNetNuke CMS. It does a pretty good job, but we're in the market for another solution. I'm particularly interested in something ASP.NET based and potentially compatible with Windows Azure. Open source or paid solutions are fine, but I am curious on if it is a paid solution, on why you consider it worthwhile to go with that over an open source platform.

Here is what our CMS should need to do.  Some of these are an assumption, but hopefully it narrows down some.

1. Easy content build out — Marketing team should be able to generate general content items, landing pages and news items on the fly
2. Media integration — Youtube, hosted videos/audio, infographics and interactive graphics, the CMS should have flexibility in hosting said content
3. Ease of use for adding/editing "rich content" — Our current CMS allows you to edit with HTML, but the toolset it quite difficult (it's basically a textbox, and all line formatting of the HTML is blown away once you save it)
4. Assistance with design/skinning — we're open to paying for a package that comes with an implementation team who can help with the site design.
5. Compatibility with custom web applications — So if we have to write some code.. such as a "find a store" locator with a map, how easily can we integrate that?  Right now everything is done via an iFrame, but it would be nice to know what alternatives we have for "custom code"
6. Integration with 3rd party API's — We use Google Analytics, and may start using HubSpot in the near future, but hopefully these types of items don't cause an issue
7. Hosting — If the service is provided, we're open to having a hosted solution, as long as it doesn't limit the above items in any way.  If we can/need to host it ourselves, it should be compatible in a Windows Azure environment if possible.

Comment: "We're still determining what we need the CMS to do": We need to know exactly *this* to make recommendations. Currently, your question is way too broad because *any* ASP.NET CMS could be a valid answer. Please [edit] your question and list exactly which features you need.

Comment: Congrats, i officially give up

Comment: This question is very close to being reopened - only 1 vote needed now - don't give up!